# C# Server Timeout Not detected at client side

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, timeout, tcpclient

I'm writing a C# TCP socket server, and I'm having trouble detecting the disconnects due to timeouts.

I mean, I configure the server  with a certain timeout, and then close the client & networkstream (I've also tried with socket) if nothing is written.

This is not being detected on client side. The client executes the "write" anyway and exits without any error.

This is the code of the server:

Thanks,
Fabian

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class MyTcpServer {

    private const int BUFSIZE = 32;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int servPort = 5009;
        TcpListener listener = null;
        try {

            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, servPort);
            listener.Start();
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
            Environment.Exit(se.ErrorCode);
        }
        byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        for (;;) {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
                socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
                Console.Write("Handling client - ");

                Console.WriteLine("Reading from client");
                socket.Receive(rcvBuffer, rcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                string line = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(rcvBuffer);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");
                socket.Close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so client code has problem but you only posted server code?